# Posting back selected dynamic radio button value in MVC4 razor

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to post back the value of a selected radio button to a controller after a button click in a MVC4 RAZOR application. I am however not getting back the real expected value in the controller, only 0.

**Partial View Code:**

```
@model Blah.FeatureViewModel
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnContinueClick() {
        $('#tabs').load('@Url.Action("Continue", "Home")', { SelectedFeature : Model.SelectedFeature });
    }
</script> 

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @foreach (var feature in Model.FeatureDictionary)
        {
            <p>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.SelectedFeature, feature) @feature.Value
            </p>       
        }

        <input type="button" name="continueButton" id="continueButton" value="Continue" onclick="OnContinueClick()" />
    </div>
}
```

**View Model Code:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Blah.Models
{
    public class FeatureViewModel
    {
        public Dictionary<int, string> FeatureDictionary { get; set; }
        public KeyValuePair<int, string> SelectedFeature { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller Code:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Continue(FeatureViewModel featureViewModel)
{
    //pass data to another controller
}
```

I think I may need to Jquery to postback the value?

Comment: Is your object being passed to load getting constructed properly? What does the JSON look like when it's all formatted? Also, it looks like your `Continue` method accepts a `FeatureViewModel`, but you aren't passing a `FeatureViewModel` object. You're passing `SelectedFeature` which is a `KVP<int, string>`.

Comment: Instead of a KVP I modified the action to take an int as that is the only value that is needed by the controller. I am having problems getting the selected value in the JS function and for that value to get sent back to the controller. The JSON initially looked like a KVP converted into a string in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

The value you are passing to the jQuery `load` function is the value of the Model at the time the view is rendered.  To pass the currently selected value you need to so something like:

```
$('#tabs').load('@Url.Action("Continue", "Home")',
                { SelectedFeature : $('[name="SelectedFeature"]').val() });
```

Also as **Joel Etherton** said, you need to change the type of your action from `FeatureViewModel` to `KeyValuePair<int, string>`.

I'm not sure

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.SelectedFeature, feature)
```

is giving you want you want either because feature is a `KeyValuePair<int, string>`. What are you attempting to create a radio button of exactly?

Comment: This creates a radio button which shows some Product(Feature) names per button and should post back the ID of the feature.

Comment: @Vapen Than you probably just need your action method to take an argument of the type of the ID, `int` I assume.